# Counting similar entries in a column

Tags: sqlite

Let's say I am counting the surnames in a census as follows:

```
select surname, count(*) from census where (surname like "Mc%" or surname like "Mac%" or surname like "Mag%") group by surname order by count(*) desc;
```

and getting the following:

```
McGee 1000
McDonald 990
Mc Gee 221
Magee 210
McGinn 200
Macdonald 100    
Maginn 30
```

Is there a way in sqlite to get the following result or should I stick to programming this result instead:

```
MACGEE 1221
MACDONALD 1090     
MAGEE 210   
MACGINN 200
MAGINN 30
```

So I'm grouping McX, Mc X and MacX as one surname.

Comment: How would you get 'Magee' and 'Maginn' in the results?

Comment: @forpas By correcting my question :)

Comment: @forpas I realise now the Mag example is more complicated so I think it is best not to group it with Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE that returns all the prefixes and their replacements (if any) that you want in the results and join it to the table.
Make all necessary replacements and then group by the resulting surname:

```
WITH cte(prefix, replacement) AS (VALUES ('MC', 'MAC'), ('MAC', 'MAC'), ('MAG', 'MAG'))
SELECT UPPER(c.replacement || SUBSTR(REPLACE(t.surname, ' ', ''), LENGTH(c.prefix) + 1)) name,
       COUNT(*) total 
FROM tablename t INNER JOIN cte c
ON t.surname LIKE c.prefix || '%'
GROUP BY name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=dcb6ec58645bacd44286ac7da76f0cc0).